# Avoid Banana In A Box in primeng listbox component

Tags: angular, primeng, two-way-binding

I'm using `primeng listbox` component, and want to avoid `banana in a box` 2 way data binding, as it's not recommended.
html side gives this:

```
<p-listbox [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"></p-listbox>
```

and `TS` side only the declaration of `selectedCity` for now:

```
selectedCity: City;
```

and `City` is an interface:

```
export Interface City {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   continent: string;
}
```

And by avoiding BIAB => have an input to my listbox component, so I can pass the selected city as a parameter, and an output to emit when selection done.

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS, too many two-way bindings can hinder performance as it can create too many watchers.

However, in Angular, two-way bindings is simply a syntactic sugar of applying both property binding and event binding.

So, you don't really have to avoid two-way binding in Angular.

See https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding--- for more info.

Comment: actually, 2-way-data-binding is not a good practice to use on the projects I work on, because it doesn't support immutability, and it doesn't permit to control the parameters when component receive them from parents, with BIAB it updates the binding data in parent too mutely which I don't want to (add to all of that, hell to debug muted data)
so to sum up, I don't want to use 2 way data binding